# Divide a Column based on two Data Frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames, df and df2, that look like:

> df

```
        User    Lab    Score
         A      1021    12
         A      1022    10
         A      1024    15
         B      1021    9
         B      1022    9
         B      1023    14
         C      1024    10
```

df2

```
        Lab    Score
        1021    15
        1022    10
        1023    15
        1024    15
```

I want to divide the Score column in df by the Score column in df2, depending on the Lab. Therefore I want to end up with a data frame that looks like:

```
        User    Lab    Score
        A       1021   0.8
        A       1022   1.0
        A       1024   1.0
        B       1021   0.6
        B       1022   0.9
        B       1023   0.93
        C       1024   0.67
```

where 12/15 = 0.8, 10/10 = 1.0, 15/15 = 1.0,9/15 = 0.6, 9/10 = 0.9, 14/15 = 0.9333, 10/15 = 0.6667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the Labs up like this:

```
df$Score <- df$Score / df2$Score[ match( df$Lab , df2$Lab ) ]
#  User  Lab     Score
#1    A 1021 0.8000000
#2    A 1022 1.0000000
#3    A 1024 1.0000000
#4    B 1021 0.6000000
#5    B 1022 0.9000000
#6    B 1023 0.9333333
#7    C 1024 0.6666667
```

`match` returns the index of the *first* match of it's first argument in it's second argument. In English it returns which row in `df2` is the match for each Lab in `df`.